# Android Dialog showing null pointer when trying to post a Dialog form to a http URL

Tags: android, http, dialog

I am new to android and this is my question, I have a dialog form that pops up which is suppose to submit a form to a URL using android Http post, when I click the submit button of the form it force closes the app and I get an error message from the logcat saying its a null pointer.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
            //This shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog 
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.commentlayout, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.Submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    postComment();

                }
            })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancal, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                }
            }).create();
    }
    return null;
}

//this comes after the setContentView(R.Layout.view)

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    public void postComment() {

        nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        countryField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        commentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentField);

        //get message from message fields
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();
        String count = countryField.getText().toString();
        String comm = commentField.getText().toString();

        //check whether the name field is empty or not
        if (name.length() > 0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://_______");

            try {
                List < NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > (3);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namet", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryt", count));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentt", comm));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);

                nameField.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                countryField.setText("");
                commentField.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //display message if text field is empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error from LogCat ?

Comment: Can you tell at which place you get null pointer exception?

Comment: thank you guys for your response, i get it at this place,  String  name = nameField.getText().toString();

Comment: is `nameField` initialized?

Comment: Please if you guys have a solution or better way of doing this kindly answer, i will be glad to accept your answer if it works. you can edit the code i have posted

Comment: @blessed, Glad to help. Great pleasure if you up-vote answer. I am editing my answer to explain your further question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` and other 2 with following code.

```
nameField = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
countryField = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
commentField = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.commentField);
```

**Edit**

> Why textEntryView was added to it?

Answer is, when you use any layout, it has **root** view. That root view is used to fetch out its children based on their "resource ids".

When you select two different layout in your activity, it means that there are two root views, one is used by `your Activity` which can be accessed by `ActivityName.this.findViewById()` method of activity. But if you want to use another layout, you need to add reference of another root view which is in your case `textEntryView`. So children are searched in that root only.

Comment: thank you the trophy goes to you, for your excellent answer. it worked. i just tried it. but please can you explain why textEntryView was added to it so this can help other people who might later face similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the following views are from `R.layout.commentlayout`

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getApplicationContext);
```

Replace the following,

```
nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
countryField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
commentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentField);
```

with

```
nameField = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
countryField = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
commentField = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.commentField);
```

Comment: I will try this approach now and get back to you immediately